# SSL with Node.js express server

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https

I have a website on a vps server running on Node.js express, I connect via http to the domain, everything works.

I'm trying to connect ssl certificates to connect via https, but still the browser says that the connection is not secure. Certificates received from the resource where I bought the domain, I was given a certificate, a root certificate, an intermediate certificate, a certificate request and a private key.

I tried to connect it like this:

```
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'./cert/private.key')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'./cert/certificate.crt')),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './cert/certificate_ca.crt'))
}
```

The certificate_ca and certificate files were sent to me by mail, and I created the private key myself (I just copied the contents from the mail there).

What am I doing wrong? Never worked with ssl. Can you help me?

UPDATED: Here's my full server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require("path")
const cors = require('cors')
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' })

const app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(cors())
app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
const logger = require('./middleware/logger')
const indexRouter = require('./routes/pocketsage')
const error_404 = require('./middleware/error-404')
app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use(error_404)
app.use(logger)
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'./cert/pocketsage.key')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'./cert/pocketsage.crt')),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './cert/pocketsage_ca.crt'))
}

const sslServer = https.createServer(options,app);
sslServer.listen(80,()=>{
    console.log('Secure server is listening on port 80')
})
```

That's what Google Chrome says:

```
This server could not prove that it is localhost; its security certificate is from www.pocketsage.ru.
This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

If I try to use it on my VPS server I get this error:

```
This server could not prove that it is 89.108.102.85; its security certificate is from www.pocketsage.ru. 
This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

And I can only connect with my IP, domain doesn't work

Comment: What are you doing with `options`? In what way does the browser say it isn't secure (make sure you click on any "advanced" or "more information" buttons)?

Comment: I'll add some more code to my question

Comment: "This server could not prove that it is localhost" — Sounds like you are testing certs intended for your VPS deployment locally and the domain name doesn't match.

Comment: I'll try using vps and update question

Comment: Updated, nothing changed, and I can't use my domain now